# what is the output of pointer problem related to array in c and why?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am not able to predict the answer of this problem and not able get a solution logically? though it may be a bit simple but as a beginner, I am not able to get it?

```
int main()
{
    int array[5][5];
    printf("%d",( (array == *array) && (*array == array[0]) ));
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///XzkzLzmnNCVVwaa4JCUzXy/DjosrM69EITcxM09Dk6uaSwEIQAKJRUWJldGmsUBkDRYsKAIKp2koqaYo6WgoaIDlFWxtFbTALE0FNTUFDS24KES7QaymgqYmRH9RaklpUZ6CgTWIw1X7/z8A "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: why do u need to predict it when u can run it? https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: @bhanu-arora Do you need to explain the output ?

Comment: I am facing conceptual problem in this problem , so I want a proper explaination  ?

Comment: This code violates constraints on operands of `==` and will not compile without diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` is the address of the begin of the array.
`*array` is the address of the begin of the first row of the array. Which also is the begin of the array. Thats why they are equal .

`array[0]` ist the first element of the two-dimensional array, so it is the first row of the array. Thats why `array[0]` and `*array` are equal.

As both comparisons result in 1 the result in total is 1.

EDIT:
Have a look at the visualisation of the array. Each "cell" has its own address, increasing from left to right per row.
The address of the beginning of the array and the address of the beginning of the first row is exactly the same. Both addresses point to the same cell.

[image]

Comment: array is the address of first element and *array is the first row element's address , how they can be equal they are addresses? please explain this point to me?

Comment: Actually `array[0] == *(array + 0) == *array`, and more generally, `array[i] == *(array + i*sizeof(*array))`

Comment: @e2-e4 ,i am facing difficulty with this part only:-              
                              (array == *array)

Comment: @BhanuArora Having `int a[5] = {0};` (items at zero) then `a != *a` (i.e. comparing the address of `a` to its 1st value, 0).  In C `int a[6][8]'` creates 48 `int` contiguous in mem,  `a[b][c]` translates to `*(a + ((b x 8) + c) x sizeof(int))`. Using 1 dimension only, `a[3]`, C will *not* give you 8 values, `a[3][0] ... a[3][7]`, that does not make sense. Instead, C evaluates the expression to the address of that 4th row of 8 items, `a + 3 x 8 x sizeof(int)`. In your case, asking `array[0]` gives you the address of the 1st row, which is at the beginning, i.e. the same as `array`.

Comment: I've added a picture to my answer. Maybe it is more understandable this way.

Answer (score 2):

Basically its a simple addressing question.

1. Is the address of `array` the same as the address of `*array`? (Yes, though they differ in type - different arrays)
2. Is Is the address of `*array` the same as the address of `array[0]`? (Yes, they are the same - the 1st int array inside `array`)
3. Now `1 && 1` evaluates to 1 (Boolean condition evaluates to 1 or 0)

PS. As @Lundin says, this question is not valid C

Comment: here array is pointer to first element of array whereas the *array is value stored in first element , how they are same? explain me

Comment: @CIsForCookies: `array` is not an `int **`. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: `array == *array` doesn't compile so there is no deterministic result of that operation.

Comment: @Lundin IDK. The online compiler I used (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), as well as this one (https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///XzkzLzmnNCVVwaa4JCUzXy/DjosrM69EITcxM09Dk6uaSwEIQAKJRUWJldGmsUBkDRYsKAIKp2koqaYo6WgoaIDlFWxtFbTALE0FNTUFDS24KES7QaymgqYmRH9RaklpUZ6CgTWIw1X7/z8A) seems to be OK with it... Additionally, treating both `array` and `*array` as `void*` will yield the same address, which is to say the are equal (address-wise at least - which is, IMO the question here), is it not?

Comment: See my answer, and in particular this: [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277340)

Answer (score 1):

- `array` when used in an expression decays to type `int (*)[5]`.
- `*array` gives the type `int*`.

These are not compatible pointer types. The requirement for pointer operands of `==` is (C17 6.5.9):

> **Constraints**
> /--/
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;

Therefore `array == *array` is not valid C, it's a constraint violation. So it gives no deterministic output and if you got an executable out of this code, it is anyone's guess what it does. Speculating about what "code which is not C" does is pretty pointless overall. At best there's some non-standard compiler extension present.

"But it compiles" - no it doesn't compile cleanly, see [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277340)

`*array` and `array[0]` however mean the same thing and you compare `int*` operands which is fine.